# Как убрать плеер на заблокированном экране после окончания воспроизвения в iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, аудио, background, ios10

При воспроизведении звука в бэкграунде, на заблокированном экране появляется плеер. Как его убрать, когда звуковой файл закончил воспроизводится?

Если, после окончания воспроизведения, установить:

```
MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.default().nowPlayingInfo = nil
```

плеер все равно остается, но с незаполненными полями

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, как оказалось, этот момент по какой-то причине просто не работает в iOS 11.2.5 (тестовое устройство), но работает, как и ожидалось (т.е. плеер исчезает) на последних версиях iOS (11.4.x). На устройствах с iOS 10 пока проверить не удалось